# Select both min Date and max date for the field at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which returns the min date value respective to the field.

```
SELECT sa.ContentID, SA.MSISDN, sa.DateRegistered AS minDate, sa.DateRegistered AS maxDate 
FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive AS sa 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MSISDN, MIN(DateRegistered) AS mindate 
            FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive 
            GROUP BY MSISDN) mysa 
ON sa.MSISDN = mysa.MSISDN AND sa.DateRegistered = mysa.mindate
```

It's output is

[image]

But I want to display the max date value for the same date as well in addition to min date. How do i achieve that?

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql", but the syntax suggests SQL Server.  Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it may be tempting to use a second subquery join to get the `MAX()`, and again join it by`MSISDN` an the max date, you should be able to achieve it by adding the `MAX(DateRegistered)` into the existing subquery and adding an `OR` condition in the join's `ON` clause to join either on the `MSISDN,mindate` or on `MSISDN,maxdate`.

```
SELECT
  sa.ContentID,
  SA.MSISDN,
  -- Use the join's dates by alias in the SELECT
  mysa.mindate,
  mysa.maxdate
FROM
  sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive AS sa 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      MSISDN,
      MIN(DateRegistered) AS mindate,
      -- Add the max date
      MAX(DateRegistered) AS maxdate,
    FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive 
    GROUP BY MSISDN
  ) mysa 
    -- Join on either a mindate or maxdate match
    ON (sa.MSISDN = mysa.MSISDN AND sa.DateRegistered = mysa.mindate)
      OR (sa.MSISDN = mysa.MSISDN AND sa.DateRegistered = mysa.maxdate)
```

I notice that you tagged this as [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) but the `dbo` really suggests you are using MS SQL Server. If that is true, then you can use a common table expression rather than the subquery join.

```
-- Define the subquery as a CTE instead
WITH mysa AS (
 SELECT
    MSISDN,
    MIN(DateRegistered) AS mindate,
    -- Add the max date
    MAX(DateRegistered) AS maxdate,
  FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive 
  GROUP BY MSISDN
);

SELECT
  sa.ContentID,
  SA.MSISDN,
  -- Use the join's dates by alias in the SELECT
  mysa.mindate,
  mysa.maxdate
FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive AS sa
-- Join on the CTE
INNER JOIN mysa
  ON (sa.MSISDN = mysa.MSISDN AND sa.DateRegistered = mysa.mindate)
  OR (sa.MSISDN = mysa.MSISDN AND sa.DateRegistered = mysa.maxdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax suggests SQL Server.  If so, I would suggest window functions:

```
SELECT sa.ContentID, SA.MSISDN, sa.DateRegistered AS minDate, sa.DateRegistered AS maxDate 
FROM (SELECT sa.*,
             MIN(DateRegistered) OVER (PARITION BY sa.MSISDN) as mindr,
             MAX(DateRegistered) OVER (PARITION BY sa.MSISDN) as maxdr
      FROM sms.dbo.SubscriptionsArchive sa 
     ) sa
WHERE sa.DateRegistered IN (mindr, maxdr);
```